# JSON in HTML <input> name attribute?

Tags: html, json, input

Is it valid in HTML to have JSON as the input name, if properly escaped?

Ie:

```
<input type="text" name="{\"object\": \"value\", \"another object\": \"another value\"}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [ye older HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) doc, actually, no:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

... though validators may have a different thoughts about it, of course. )

Comment: Thanks for referencing the W3C.

Answer (score 2):

1. You didn't escape it properly. The proper escaping would be to replace all `"`s with `&quot;`s.
2. Yes, it is valid, but it seems like a very wrong idea in the first place. Why do you need to index your fields with json data instead of a simple string keys?

Comment: Ah, indeed. I had a minor brain fart. I'm mixing PHP with HTML in my head. Long day.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid, but that's *not* how you escape quotes in HTML. You use character entities. In this case, it's `&quot;`; not `\"`.

However, usually, you use a `name` attribute for submission to a server. That's an awkward parameter name. Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps that was a kind of server-side json'ing client-side response attempt, or something similar. )

Comment: Yeah, it does seem awkward, but it would be an excellent way to pass additional information about the input, that isn't defined by the user.

Comment: @Yoshiyahu: `<input type="hidden" name="extraData" value="{put: all, your: &quot;JSON&quot;, here: '!'}" />` That's what it's there for :)

Comment: That doesn't stick to the input in question though. It could be made to, but I might as well find another method to pass data.

Comment: @Yoshiyahu: What do you mean it "doesn't stick"?

Comment: An input is considered a key-value pair in server-side languages. By making the key JSON, I was attempting to make the key hold more complex data then is usually held.  
  
So, by doesn't stick, I mean I would have to reference another key-value pair to get the extra information. :/ More or less an extra step.